# Getting New Field using the CMS Service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Had some trouble getting the newly created fields using the "this.cmsservice.getcurrentpage()".

I've tried extending the PageNormalizer, but unsuccessful.

Any idea or workaround.

Comment: Can you explain where you added custom fields? Was it on the page itself, or on a specific compknent?

Comment: on the page itself. the payload kinda looks like this.. 

    <label>/testLabel</label>
    <category>TEST CATEGORY</category>
  </page>

should i just put it in a component level?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by extending/overriding the 'CMS_PAGE_NORMALIZER'. Added the new field under the properties of the original structure.

See below code:

```
export class pageNormalizer implements Converter<Occ.CMSPage, CmsStructureModel> {
  convert(source: any, target?: CmsStructureModel): CmsStructureModel {
    target.page.properties = {
      newfield: source.newfield,
    };
    return target;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wondering if you extend the CMS model in the backend, and added a field mapping in the spring config?

Comment: It was added in the backend, as for the spring config, that I have to verify. The fix stated above suddenly stop working tho.

Answer (score -1):

Although I never worked with the spartacus-storefront, you problem seems similar to another one I´ve seen here before.

Try **this**:

https://pipedrive.readme.io/docs/adding-a-new-custom-field

Comment: thanks for this! but it seems that the cmsservice is filtering out the response.. and the newly added field in the backend was left out.